# Polynomial Length upper bound

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, induction

Define the length of a polynomial $A = a_0 + a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ to be $$L(A) = \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|$$, and let $$\lambda (r,s) : = \inf \frac{L(AB)}{L(A)L(B)}$$ where the degree of $A$ is at most $r$, and the degree of $B$ is at most $s$.

Prove that $\lambda(r,r) \leq \frac{1}{2^r}$.

I've tried two ideas, neither of which I could really get to work.
The first was an induction argument, in which I was able to successfully show the base case, but couldn't get the inductive step.

The second thought I had was to see if I could just explicitly find polynomials $A$ and $B$ that have length $(1/2)^r$ for any $r$, that would also work to show the infimum is less then that value.

Any hints or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Comment: This is from Dr. David Masser's book titled Auxilliary polynomials, and it's problem 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, let $A(x):=(1+x)^r$ and $B(x):=(1-x)^r$.  Then, $$L(A)=L(B)=L(AB)=2^r\,.$$  That is,
$$\frac{L(AB)}{L(A)\,L(B)}=\frac{1}{2^r}\,.$$
Hence,
$$\lambda(r,r)\leq \frac{1}{2^r}\,.$$

There are some easy-to-prove results.  First, $\lambda(r,0)=\lambda(0,r)=1$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  Next, $$\lambda(r,1)=\lambda(1,r)\leq \dfrac{1}{r+1}$$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, where the equality holds, at least, for $r=1$.  Finally, for all positive integers $r$ and $s$, we get
$$\lambda(r,rs)=\lambda(rs,r)\leq \dfrac{1}{(s+1)^r}\,.$$

Comment: I knew there was something simple, thanks a ton.

Comment: @JonHales Does the book mention any specific formula for $\lambda(r,s)$?  It would be interesting to know.

Comment: It does not, the concept was introduced in the exercises. It might in some later chapters. I'll let you know if it turns up.

Comment: Please do.  This is an interesting problem.  So, I would greatly appreciate what you'd find out.

Comment: I asked my professor today during lecture, and he said as far as he was concerned, currently in the literature, there is no known solution for how to calculate $\lambda(r,s)$ for a given $r$ and $s$. Sounds like an interesting research problem!